# Empty stacktrace in exceptions

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, jvm, stack-trace

I am debugging tomcat application with spring. I am using jdk1.7.0_25 and apache-tomcat-7.0.35 with -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow:

[image: my tomca settings]

but I still get NPEs and SQLExceptions with no stack trace information. It is like C++ debugging. What's wrong?

[image: typical exception]

Thanx for any ideas!

Comment: Is your code compiled with debug informations?
Check javac options, for example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html

Comment: @robermann, Yes, i can debug properly, set watches, see stack, etc. But exceptions's stack trace is empty.

Comment: Try running with `-Xint`

Comment: @jdb, this doesn't help for some unknown reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugger never shows ex.stackTrace member. At least in Intellij or in other debugger, ex.getStackTrace() should be used.